# How to pass arguments to a method loaded from a static library in CPP

Tags: c++, static-libraries, dlopen, dynamic-library, method-call

I'm trying to write a program to use a static library of a C++ code into another C++ code. The first C++ code is `hello.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
extern "C" void say_hello(const char* name) {
    cout << "Hello " <<  name << "!\n";
}
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

The I made a static library from this code, `hello.a`, using this command:

```
g++ -o hello.a -static -fPIC hello.cpp -ldl
```

Here's the second C++ code to use the library, `say_hello.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    void* handle = dlopen("./hello.a", RTLD_LAZY);
    cout<<handle<<"\n";
    if (!handle) {
        cerr<<"Cannot open library: "<<dlerror()<<'\n';
        return 1;
    }
    typedef void (*hello_t)();
    dlerror(); // reset errors
    hello_t say_hello = (hello_t) dlsym(handle, "say_hello");
    const char *dlsym_error = dlerror();
    if (dlsym_error) {
        cerr<<"Cannot load symbol 'say_hello': "<<dlsym_error<<'\n';
        dlclose(handle);
        return 1;
    }
    say_hello("World");
    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled `say_hello.cpp` using:

```
g++ -W -ldl say_hello.cpp -o say_hello
```

and ran `./say_hello` in the command line. I expected to get `Hello World!` as output, but I got this instead:

```
0x8ea4020
Hello ▒▒▒▒!
```

What is the problem? Is there any trick to make compatibility for method's argument like what we use in [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) or what?

If it helps I use a lenny.

**EDIT 1:**

I have changed the code and used a dynamic library, 'hello.so', which I've created using this command:

```
g++ -o hello.so -shared -fPIC hello.cpp -ldl
```

The 6th line of the code changed to:

```
void* handle = dlopen("./hello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

When I tried to compile `say_hello.cpp`, I got this error:

```
say_hello.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
say_hello.cpp:21: error: too many arguments to function
```

I also tried to compile it using this line:

```
g++ -Wall -rdynamic say_hello.cpp -ldl -o say_hello
```

But same error raised. So I removed the argument `"World"` and the it has been compiled with no error; but when I run the executable, I get the same output like I have mentioned before.

**EDIT 2:**

Based on @Basile Starynkevitch 's suggestions, I changed my `say_hello.cpp` code to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    void* handle = dlopen("./hello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    cout<<handle<<"\n";
    if (!handle) {
        cerr<<"Cannot open library: "<<dlerror()<<'\n';
        return 1;
    }
    typedef void hello_sig(const char *);
    void* hello_ad = dlsym(handle, "say_hello");
    if (!hello_ad){
        cerr<<"dlsym failed:"<<dlerror()<<endl;
        return 1;
    }
    hello_sig* fun = reinterpret_cast<hello_sig*>(hello_ad);
    fun("from main");
    fun = NULL;
    hello_ad = NULL;
    dlclose(handle);
    return 0;
}
```

Before that, I used below line to make a `.so` file:

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -g -shared hello.cpp -o hello.so
```

Then I compiled `say_hello.cpp` wth this command:

```
g++ -Wall -rdynamic -g say_hello.cc -ldl -o say_hello
```

And then ran it using `./say_hello`. Now everything is going right. Thanks to @Basile Starynkevitch for being patient about my problem.

Comment: Why do you use a *static library* `hello.a` instead of a *shared object dynamic library* `hello.so`? Do you have to use a *static* library? If yes, why???

Comment: Also, you are not `dlsym`-ing a *method* but a *function*

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I used the shared library and updated the question. BTW I don't really understand what you said in the second comment.

Comment: A matter of terminology.

Comment: Your `hello_t` typedef is wrong.

Comment: It is exactly what has been said in the [documentation](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/).

Comment: But in the documentation no argument is passed to hello.

Comment: You're right, I'll try your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions never have null addresses, so `dlsym` on a function name (or actually on any name defined in C++ or C) cannot be `NULL` without failing:

```
hello_t say_hello = (hello_t) dlsym(handle, "say_hello");
if (!say_hello) {
    cerr<<"Cannot load symbol 'say_hello': "<<dlerror()<<endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
};
```

And [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) is documented to [dynamically load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) only *dynamic libraries* (not static ones!). This implies *shared objects* (`*.so`) in [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) format. Read Drepper's paper [How To Use Shared Libraries](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

I believe you might have found a bug in `dlopen` (see also its [POSIX dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/dlopen.html) specification); it should fail for a static library `hello.a`; it is *always used on position independent shared libraries* (like `hello.so`).

**You should `dlopen` only [position independent code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) [*shared objects*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29#Shared_libraries)** compiled with

```
g++ -Wall -O -shared -fPIC hello.cpp -o hello.so
```

or if you have several C++ source files:

```
g++ -Wall -O -fPIC src1.cc -c -o src1.pic.o
g++ -Wall -O -fPIC src2.cc -c -o src2.pic.o
g++ -shared src1.pic.o src2.pic.o -o yourdynlib.so
```

<sup>you could remove the `-O` optimization flag or add `-g` for debugging or replace it with `-O2` if you want.</sup>

and this works extremely well: my [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) project (a domain specific language to extend GCC) is using this a lot (generating C++ code, forking a compilation like above on the fly, then `dlopen`-ing the resulting *shared object*). And my [manydl.c](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/manydl.c) example demonstrates that you can `dlopen` a big lot of (different) shared objects on Linux (typically millions, and hundred of thousands at least). Actually the limitation is the address space.

<sup>BTW, you should not `dlopen` something having a `main` function, since `main` is by definition defined in the main program calling (perhaps indirectly) `dlopen`.</sup>

Also, order of arguments to `g++` matters a lot; you should compile the main program with

```
g++ -Wall -rdynamic say_hello.cpp -ldl -o say_hello
```

<sup>The `-rdynamic` flag is required to let the loaded plugin (`hello.so`) call functions from inside your `say_hello` program.</sup>

For debugging purposes always pass `-Wall -g` to `g++` above.

<sup>BTW, you could in principle `dlopen` a shared object which don't have PIC (i.e. was not compiled with `-fPIC`); but it is much better to `dlopen` some PIC shared object.</sup>

Read also the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and the [C++ dlopen mini-howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/) (because of [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)).

---

#### example

File `helloshared.cc` (my tiny plugin source code in C++) is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
extern "C" void say_hello(const char* name) {
    cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " hello " 
         <<  name << "!" << endl;
}
```

and I am compiling it with:

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -g -shared helloshared.cc -o hello.so
```

The main program is in file `mainhello.cc` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " starting." << endl;
    void* handle = dlopen("./hello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        cerr << "dlopen failed:" << dlerror() << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    };
    // signature of loaded function
    typedef void hello_sig_t(const char*);
    void* hello_ad = dlsym(handle,"say_hello");
    if (!hello_ad) {
        cerr << "dlsym failed:" << dlerror() << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    hello_sig_t* fun = reinterpret_cast<hello_sig_t*>(hello_ad);
    fun("from main");
    fun = NULL; hello_ad = NULL;
    dlclose(handle);
    cout << __FILE__ << ":" << __LINE__ << " ended." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which I compile with

```
g++ -Wall -rdynamic -g mainhello.cc -ldl -o mainhello
```

Then I am running `./mainhello` with the expected output:

```
mainhello.cc:7 starting.
helloshared.cc:5 hello from main!
mainhello.cc:24 ended.
```

Please notice that the signature `hello_sig_t` in `mainhello.cc` should be compatible (homomorphic, i.e. the same as) with the function `say_hello` of the `helloshared.cc` plugin, otherwise it is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and you probably would have a `SIGSEGV` crash).

Comment: I will try to use shared libraries with creating a `.o` file beforehand. I will update the question about the results.

Comment: BTW what is `src1.cc`? Did you mean `src1.cpp`?

Comment: The `.cc` and `.cxx` and `.cpp` are valid file extensions for C++ source code given to `g++`. I prefer to use `.cc`

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I'm still trying.

Comment: I will if I get to the desired result by trying your suggested ways :)